# KiCad netlist output GND not labeled 0 for Ngspice

Tags: ground, kicad, ngspice

As the title suggests, I'm having trouble generating netlist from KiCad for Ngspice, the problem being that I can't get KiCad to output a "0" node for "ground".

I'm aware that I'm supposed to use the "0" as my ground from the pspice library, but somehow it doesn't work for me. 
[image: Using "0" as ground.]
[image]

I found this guide [KiCAD Schematic: Naming Nets and ngspice Simulation in Linux](http://karibe.co.ke/2017/06/kicad-schematic-naming-nets-and-ngspice-simulation-in-linux/), which seems to address the exact issue I'm experiencing; however, when the guide says

> You can use Global labels instead of net name labels. When you use Global labels, the net names in the netlist are OK. Use 0 for reference instead of GND or Ground. That way it will be interpreted as 0 volts in the simulation.

I'm not getting the same result as the guide suggests; in fact, nothing really changed on my end. Attached are screenshots of my schematics and their corresponding netlist outputs.
[image: A simple voltage divider circuit. Using Global label as "ground".]
[image: Netlist output.]

I'm running KiCad Version 4.0.2+dfsg1-stable release build on Ubuntu 16.04.

I've poured hours in this trying to find an answer online, but none of the existing Q&A's seem to address this problem fully. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think KiCad 4.0.2 is too old, it works correctly in 5.0.0-rc2-215-g0748c118d. Try a newer version. KiCad v5 will be released quite soon...

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed the older version that was causing the problem. Everything works find now after I upgraded it to kicad
version 5.0.0-fee4fd1~65~ubuntu16.04.1, release build.